# jcl-slf4j and axis 1.4 exception while substituting commons-logging

Tags: java, logging, axis, slf4j

We are trying to substitute commons-logging + log4j by jcl-over-slf4j and logback (OK, at first we will try jcl-over-slf4j and log4j). Our application runs under WAS 8.0. Once the commons-logging jar has been erased and substituted by jcl-over-slf4j, slf4j and slf4j-log4j, we get this error message:

```
[21/11/14 16:12:08:430 CET] 0000006a webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp commonInitializationFinally SRVE0266E: Se ha producido un error al inicializar los servlets: {0}
                                 javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: No se ha detectado la excepción de inicialización creada por el servlet
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:404)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.init(ServletWrapperImpl.java:168)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadOnStartupCheck(ServletWrapper.java:1366)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.doLoadOnStartupActions(WebApp.java:615)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinally(WebApp.java:584)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:421)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:749)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:422)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:714)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1164)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1369)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:967)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:770)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1361)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2162)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:446)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:389)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:117)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:664)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5468)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5594)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:678)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:622)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1251)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor71.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:260)
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1141)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1135)
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:988)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:835)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:771)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.CallRouter.route(CallRouter.java:247)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.doWork(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:360)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink$IPCConnectorReadCallback.complete(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:602)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1819)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:558)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:608)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:985)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1074)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1702)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tareaIntegrationLectSolicitNuevasFacturas': Autowiring of fields failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private es.nexus.facturaelectronica.service.interfaces.integrations.IIntegracionPersistirNuevasFacturas es.nexus.facturaelectronica.service.impl.integrations.IntegrationLectSolicitNuevasFacturas.integracionPersistirNuevasFacturas; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tareaIntegrationPersistirNuevasFacturas' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/bean-application-config.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInstantiation(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:243)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:959)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:221)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:729)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:381)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1686)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:410)
        ... 53 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private es.nexus.facturaelectronica.service.interfaces.integrations.IIntegracionPersistirNuevasFacturas es.nexus.facturaelectronica.service.impl.integrations.IntegrationLectSolicitNuevasFacturas.integracionPersistirNuevasFacturas; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tareaIntegrationPersistirNuevasFacturas' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/bean-application-config.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:435)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.injectFields(InjectionMetadata.java:105)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInstantiation(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:240)
        ... 71 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tareaIntegrationPersistirNuevasFacturas' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/bean-application-config.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:480)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:221)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:671)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:610)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:412)
        ... 73 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc.<clinit>(TypeDesc.java:61)
        at es.gob.face.webservice.SRCFFactura.<clinit>(SRCFFactura.java:196)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy450.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newInstance(Proxy.java:715)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:706)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.getProxy(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:117)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:110)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:488)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:363)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:324)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:361)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1343)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
        ... 84 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.discovery.DiscoveryException: Class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl does not implement org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
        at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.ClassUtils.verifyAncestory(ClassUtils.java:180)
        at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.SPInterface.verifyAncestory(SPInterface.java:201)
        at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.SPInterface.newInstance(SPInterface.java:195)
        at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.DiscoverClass.newInstance(DiscoverClass.java:579)
        at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.DiscoverSingleton.find(DiscoverSingleton.java:418)
        at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.DiscoverSingleton.find(DiscoverSingleton.java:378)
        at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory$1.run(LogFactory.java:45)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.getLogFactory(LogFactory.java:41)
        at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.<clinit>(LogFactory.java:33)
        ... 103 more
```

It all end with the org.apache.commons.discovery.DiscoveryException: Class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl does not implement org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
error message.

Is there some kind of incompatibility between commons-logging and its jcl-over-slf4j substitute?
We've checked some other projects, and it seems a common pattern: axis 1.4 + jcl-over-slf4j = exception.

[Note 1]
Classloader policy: tests.
In order to get commons-logging working with log4j at application level, we have assigned those libraries to the application (first we declare them both as "shared libraries", and we do the same with commons-logging.properties and log4j.properties files, then We assign them all to the application, and then we set the application's classloader policy to "Parent Last". This way, we force the application to load and use it's own copy of commons-logging, with its own configuration file, thus overcoming the commons-logging.properties included within WAS. This said, we have tried some "stupid" configurations, like make all the application use a single application classloader, or setting the web modules classloader policy to Parent Last. Such changes made no difference, as expected.

This far, we have found some nasty scenarios:

1. Axis + WAS logging facility (write all to SystemOut): OK, it works,
   but we do not want everything written down to SystemOut!
2. Axis + commons-logging + log4j + their configuration files assigned
   to the application at application classloader level,policy=Parent
   Last. Some applications work, some others don't (theyshow messages
   like the one quoted before).
3. jcl-over-slf4j + log4j + configuration file for log4j: Same result
   as in point 2 of this list.

The last application we are dealing with right now, the application that fails with the excetions in the code block quoted previously: we have discovered that it only fails when we use configuration 3 (in this list), but it does not fail with configuration 2, which is very surprising and unexpected: in previous test with other applications, if the configuration fails with configuration 2, then it also fails with configuration 3.

[End of Note 1]

Any help will be welcome.

Comment: What about the parent classloader policy?

Comment: I will add some information about classloader policy with [Note 1] label.

Comment: Humm... Have you seen http://bugzilla.slf4j.org/show_bug.cgi?id=33 ?

Comment: Yes, I did. But we are trying to use slf4j 1.7.6, that includes a org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory file under services directory. Maybe something prevents Java from reading this file, (for expample, if there is another file with the same name in any other jar file)... I think I'll run some jar tvf on the set of libraries and across the platform, and I'll add a note to the help request explaining it. I'll keep yo posted (here).

Comment: I've checked it and there are'nt more occurrences of org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory into any jar file, nor into the EAR or WAR.

Answer (score 2):

We have exactly the same Setup here:

- WAS 8.0.0.9
- *log4j* for logging
- EAR containing *jcl-over-slf4j*, *slf4j* and *slf4j-log4j*
- Axis 1.4
- Classloader policy *Parent Last* and WAR policy *Single class loader for application*

As soon as axis-classes are loaded, some static-initializer-block gets executed and we get this Exception:

```
DiscoveryException: Class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl does not implement org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
```

It seems like *org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory* is loaded from *jcl-over-slf4j* and *org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl* is provided by WebSphere.

The only way it works for us, is to remove *jcl-over-slf4j.jar* from our EAR. Of course this way we might lose some Logs or find them in WebSphere SystemOut.log but at least 'it works'...

Comment: The problem with that solution is that, if you don't include the jcl-over-slf4j, then the axis calls to commons-logging are executed against the commons-logging included in WebSphere infraestructure. At best, you get the axis log messages dumped in the SystemOut.log file... which is one thing we try to avoid.

We also enabled the classloader debug trace for the server at WAS administration console, and so we could determine that commons-discovery was involved in this nightmare (as suggested by some posts in other forums)

Comment: I edited the answer to include this consequences. It seems there is no way to get 'it running' and have logging with log4j working too. We accept that and will not invest more time in finding a solution...

Comment: in my case, upgrading commons-logging-1.0.3 to version 1.0.4 seemed to fix the DiscoveryException

Answer (score 2):

We encountered the same issues. Our solution is to tell commons-logging to use the slf4j factory implementation in our classloading context (in our case an ejb.jar).

To achieve this we simply added a commons-logging.properties file to our ejb.jar root folder with following content:

```
priority=1
org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory
```

This resolved the issue in our application.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you. I was with a similar problem, and discovered a solution in SLF4J documentation.

http://slf4j.org/faq.html#excludingJCL

> alternative 2) provided scope Commons-logging can be rather simply and
>   conveniently excluded as a dependency by declaring it in the provided
>   scope within the pom.xml file of your project. The actual
>   commons-logging classes would be provided by jcl-over-slf4j. This
>   translates into the following pom file snippet:

```
<dependency>  
   <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>  
   <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.1</version>  
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency> 

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>  
   <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.21</version>
</dependency>
```

> The first dependency declaration essentially states that
>   commons-logging will be "somehow" provided by your environment. The
>   second declaration includes jcl-over-slf4j into your project. As
>   jcl-over-slf4j is a perfect binary-compatible replacement for
>   commons-logging, the first assertion becomes true. Unfortunately,
>   while declaring commons-logging in the provided scope gets the job
>   done, your IDE, e.g. Eclipse, will still place commons-logging.jar on
>   your project's class path as seen by your IDE. You would need to make
>   sure that jcl-over-slf4j.jar is visible before commons-logging.jar by
>   your IDE.

SLF4J documentation gives more alternatives, this worked for me.